# node js upload image and upload to ftp: works for one but not two images

Tags: node.js

```
var ftpClient = new ftp();
var form = new formidable.IncomingForm();
form.parse(request, function(err, fields, files) {
    if (files.shoplogo.name) {
        var dimensions = sizeOf(files.shoplogo.path);
        console.log(dimensions.width + " x " + dimensions.height);
        if (dimensions.width > 255 || dimensions.height > 255 || dimensions.width < 145 || dimensions.height < 145) {
            response.send('<script>alert("Das Bild darf nicht größer 250x250 oder kleiner als 150x150 sein."); history.back(); </script>');
            return;
        }
        if (files.shoplogo.size > 200000) {
            response.send('<script>alert("Das Bild darf nicht größer als 150 kb sein."); history.back(); </script>');
            return;
        } else {
            var oldpath = files.shoplogo.path;
            ftpClient.on('ready', function() {
                ftpClient.put(oldpath, '/web/shopContent/' + 'logo_' + fields.shopid + ".jpg", function(err, list) {
                    if (err) throw err;
                    ftpClient.end();
                });
            });
        }
    }
    if (files.shopcover.name) {
        var dimensions = sizeOf(files.shopcover.path);
        console.log(dimensions.width + " x " + dimensions.height);
        if (dimensions.width > 505 || dimensions.height > 505 || dimensions.width < 245 || dimensions.height < 245) {
            response.send('<script>alert("Das Bild darf nicht größer 500x500 oder kleiner als 250x250 sein."); history.back(); </script>');
            return;
        }
        if (files.shopcover.size > 200000) {
            response.send('<script>alert("Das Bild darf nicht größer als 150 kb sein."); history.back(); </script>');
            return;
        } else {
            var oldpath = files.shopcover.path;
            ftpClient.on('ready', function() {
                ftpClient.put(oldpath, '/web/shopContent/' + 'cover_' + fields.shopid + ".jpg", function(err, list) {
                    if (err) throw err;
                    ftpClient.end();
                });
            });
        }
    }
    ftpClient.connect({
        'host': 'host',
        'user': 'user',
        'password': 'pw'
    });
});
```

Working from scratch I managed to code a function that allows me to upload images to my server (from client) and then to upload it to FTP server.
If the user selects one image a time everything works fine but uploading both images breaks.

I think the problem is how I handle the connection. How can I tweak the code?

Comment: What do you mean 'breaks'? Throws exception, just nothing happens, or what? If it throws, it would be helpful to know at which point. Also, note that if both fields `files.shopcover.name` and `files.shoplogo.name` exist, you will attempt to close ftp connection twice. To fix that, I would recommend either converting this function into promise-based one, or calling `ftpClient.connect()` inside each condition.

Answer (score -1):

You don't say, but I suppose that you're using the https://www.npmjs.com/package/ftp package.

First of all, please, DRY (Don't Repeat Yourself).
I've extracted a repetitive code into the `put_on_ftp()` function (see below)

```js
// nothing special here, except that I've removed
// the `ftpClient.connect` call from the `form.parse()` function
// read along...

var form = new formidable.IncomingForm();
form.parse(request, function(err, fields, files) {
  if (files.shoplogo.name) {
    put_on_ftp(
      'logo_' + fields.shopid,
      files.shoplogo,
      {size: 200000, min_w: 145, max_w: 255, min_h: 145, max_h: 255},
    )
  }
  if (files.shopcover.name) {
    put_on_ftp(
      'cover_' + fields.shopid,
      files.shopcover,
      {size: 200000, min_w: 245, max_w: 255, min_h: 245, max_h: 255},
    )
  }
});
```

Then, the docs say that

> **end()** - (void) - Closes the connection to the server after **any**/all enqueued commands have been executed.

Take a note of the "*any*" in this clause. So that means that when first of your images uploads the connection breaks while second one is still in process.

Haven't used this package myself, and even don't know if it can upload several files in parallel... and I'm not even sure if I've guessed the package right, so let's take the simplest approach - just open a new connection for each file.

```js
function put_on_ftp(file_name, file, limits)
  const dimensions = sizeOf(file.path);
  if (
    dimensions.width  > limits.max_w ||
    dimensions.height > limits.max_h ||
    dimensions.width  < limits.min_w ||
    dimensions.height < limits.min_h
  ) {
    response.send('some error');
    return;
  }
  if (file.size > limits.size) {
    response.send('some other error');
    return;
  } else {
    const ftpClient = new ftp();
    ftpClient.on('ready', function() {
      ftpClient.put(
        file.path,
        `/web/shopContent/${file_name}.jpg`,
        function(err) { // there is no `list` arguments
          if (err) throw err;
          ftpClient.end();
        });
      )
    })

    // -------------------------
    // do it here
    ftpClient.connect({
      'host': 'host',
      'user': 'user',
      'password': 'pw'
    });
    // -------------------------
  }
}
```

<sup>Also note that there is no `list` arguments in the callback of the `put()` function. And you don't use it anyway. So I've ditched it.</sup>